# export data to ms word with php

Tags: php, export, header-files

I want export table to ms word with php headers, but need change document's list type to album

```
if (isset($_GET['export']) && $_GET['export'] == 1) 
{
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=filename.doc");
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by `document's list type to album` ?

Comment: ooops sory, i mean "document's page type"